# Crash in viewWillTransitionToSize

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, orientation-changes

I am developing an app targeting iOS 8.0+ using Swift 2.2 and Realm 1.0.2 as my data store.

I am seeing lots of crashes related to this code in the crash logs although I can't currently reproduce them myself:

```
/// Resize cells when orientation changes.
override func viewWillTransitionToSize(size: CGSize, withTransitionCoordinator coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    if visible {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            if let coordinator = coordinator as UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator? {
                if self.collectionView != nil {
                    self.collectionView.reloadData()

                    coordinator.animateAlongsideTransition({ context in
                        self.collectionView.performBatchUpdates(nil, completion: nil)
                    }, completion: nil)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This code appears in a view controller that contains a `UICollectionView` which displays cells in different sizes depending on the orientation. I'm not clear on why I need `self.collectionView.reloadData()` before the animation but without it the margins are much wider than intended.

Here's the trace I get:

```
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x0000000180f400b0 objc_retain + 16 (objc-object.h:341)
1   UIKit                           0x00000001873a1570 -[_UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator _animateAlongsideTransitionInView:systemCompletion:animation:completion:] + 112 (UIViewControllerTransitioning.m:865)
2   UIKit                           0x0000000186b17f40 -[_UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator animateAlongsideTransition:completion:] + 68 (UIViewControllerTransitioning.m:906)
3   MyApp                           0x00000001000fc78c 0x1000c0000 + 247692
4   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018130d4bc _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24 (init.c:760)
5   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018130d47c _dispatch_client_callout + 16 (object.m:506)
6   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000181312b84 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 1844 (inline_internal.h:1063)
7   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000181878d50 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 12 (CFRunLoop.c:1613)
8   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000181876bb8 __CFRunLoopRun + 1628 (CFRunLoop.c:2718)
9   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001817a0c50 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 384 (CFRunLoop.c:2814)
10  GraphicsServices                0x0000000183088088 GSEventRunModal + 180 (GSEvent.c:2245)
11  UIKit                           0x0000000186a82088 UIApplicationMain + 204 (UIApplication.m:3772)
12  MyApp                           0x00000001000c92d8 0x1000c0000 + 37592
13  libdyld.dylib                   0x000000018133e8b8 start + 4 (start_glue.s:78)
```

I use to be able to trigger a similar crash by changing the orientation on another screen and then quickly coming back to the one with the `UICollectionView`. The `if visible` check seems to fix that and I'm getting a lot fewer of these crashes but still some. Any ideas on where to look for issues in my code or resources on reading these traces would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why do you have the GCD call to put your block on the main thread? I believe `viewWillTransitionToSize` (like other UIKit methods) will be called on the main thread. I'm not sure if that could cause your crash.

Comment: @DylanS That and a couple other probably unnecessary things are in there because of suggestions I found searching for the problem. My understanding is that if it's already on the main thread, the `dispatch_async` is just redundant but doesn't hurt.

Comment: That may or may not be true. Suppose Apple implemented `viewWillTransitionToSize` in such a way that once you return, any modifications to `coordinator` are invalid or unstable. Since your code is wrapped in a block sent to GCD, `viewWillTransitionToSize` will return before your block is executed (sometimes, GCD only promises to run on the given queue but not really any promises about ordering). For instance, if the view controller starts its animations... Then GCD executes your block... How might it respond to receiving additional animations halfway through? It might not be defined.

Comment: Another issue that I see is you don't forward the method to `super`. You generally always want to forward `UIViewController` lifecycle methods on to `super`. Apple specifically calls out the need to do so for [this method.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIContentContainer_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIContentContainer/viewWillTransitionToSize:withTransitionCoordinator:)

Comment: @DylanS Ah, yes, you're right, thank you! I'll make those two changes and report back after a couple of days of usage (since I don't know how to trigger the crash myself).

Comment: One thing you might try to see if it triggers the crash is delaying the `dispatch_async`, so call it as: `dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(1.0 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC))), dispatch_get_main_queue())` (change 1.0 to any number of seconds). If that crashes with a similar stack trace, you'll know it was **a** problem (perhaps not **the** problem).

Comment: @DylanS How wonderful, that does make it crash! :D I see what you mean about possibly undefined behavior. I put that in because of the initial crash reports so I'm not sure it's **the** problem, as you say, but it's certainly good to fix now.

Comment: No crashes so far so @DylanS if you write up an answer, I will accept it!

Comment: I did make one more change which may or may not have made a difference. All I need here is a layout change so I don't need the `reloadData` and `performBatchUpdates` calls and can instead use                     `invalidateLayout`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a couple small issues here:

- Always call `super` in UIViewController lifecycle methods
- The GCD call might cause unexpected inconsistencies

Keep in mind that `dispatch_async` only schedules your code block with GCD, and does not make any guarantees about when it will execute. It's entirely possible for that block to execute after the animations start, leaving the size transition in an inconsistent state.